# OpenCV: How do I write a video, and why is my frame stuck?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to get a video stream and save it using OpenCV and python-2.7. But when I run the program, it is stuck on one frame and after closing the video is broken.

What the reason for that?

This is the my code what I tried.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out=cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc,20.0,(640,480))

while True:
  ret,frame=cap.read()
  out.write(frame)
  cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
  if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in your button press at the end.

You have

`if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):`

It should be

`if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):`

Putting 0 would cause the code to reach that point, and then wait **forever** on that line.
Putting 1 allows it to wait for 1 millisecond and then move on if it doesn't happen.

There's more information on this in the docs, [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey).